# XSLT Display CHECKBOX

Tags: xslt, checkbox

I have a report in XML that is formatted using xslt. I need to display a checkbox next to some text. Currently this is the xslt

```
<TableHeaderRow>
    <TableHeaderCell  colspan="4">
        <TableCommentsText>
            &#x2610; <xsl:value-of select="/ReportForm/Comments1/Paragraph/@Text" />
        </TableCommentsText>
    </TableHeaderCell>
</TableHeaderRow>
```

This is not working. My output comes out blank before the text. If I use &# 174; (®) it's working fine.

What can I do to get the CheckBox?

Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about a `CheckBox`, but I do not see any `CheckBox` directives/commands in your code.

Comment: I am not talking about the html checkbox. The code &#x2610; is an extended ascii code that displays a small square like a checkbox. I also tried the html <input type="checkbox /> and it didn't work.

Comment: Interesting...does `<xsl:value-of select="'&#x2610; '" />`give you the desired result?

Comment: Nope this didn't work either.

Comment: "*My output comes out blank before the text.*" How exactly are you testing this? And what is your output method and encoding?

Comment: I just tried to include this UniCode `char` into one of my files and it worked as described in `FireFox` and `bash`. It displayed an empty square on the given position. Are you sure that your default font does implement this char? If your current font does not "describe" this char, you would see nothing...

Comment: Output is in PDF and encoding is utf-8.

Comment: There is something missing in your description. XSLT does not produce PDF. I believe it's safe to bet that  the **XML** produced by the XSL transformation that you show us does contain the specified character. Check what happens later in your processing chain.

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say xml. This xml is then converted in our format and exported to PDF.

Comment: I asked how are you testing this. What is the tool you are using to examine the XML that the above transformation produces?

Comment: Can you prove to the satisfaction of a distinterested third party that the font used in your eventually PDF output actually has a character for the Unicode code point in question?

Comment: Does the document that's produced by your XSLT actually have the entity `&#x2610;` in the output? If so, this is not an XSLT problem.